# Adding Product Image/Gallery Without Loading the Whole Product

Tags: magento-1, image, product-images, gallery, ee-1.14.1

Is there a way to add images to a product without loading the whole product? `updateAttributes()` is definitely fast when updating a product but when adding an image to a product, this function is needed:

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($_filepath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
```

Comment: Which Magento version are you referring to ?

Comment: It's for Magento v1.x, v1.14.1.0 to be  specific.

Comment: Is it the load or the save that is actually slowing you down? You should be able to just set the product ID on the model without loading it to add images, but saving may be slow if your indexers are set to on save